# How to get text to flash on ssd1306 i2c screen

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, display

I am trying to alternate a string back and forth on the SSD1306 oled screen.
So I want the display to show "test1" for 0.5 seconds, then "test2" for 0.5 seconds, repeating. the code below is just showing "test1" for 0.5 seconds then going blank...
I am using a ssd1306 128_32 i2c screen, and using the adafruit library.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
#define OLED_RESET     4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);

  // SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC = generate display voltage from 3.3V internally
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { // Address 0x3C for 128x32
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }

  // Show initial display buffer contents on the screen --
  // the library initializes this with an Adafruit splash screen.
  display.display();
  delay(2000); // Pause for 2 seconds

  // Clear the buffer
  display.clearDisplay();

  // Show the display buffer on the screen. You MUST call display() after
  // drawing commands to make them visible on screen!
  display.display();
  delay(2000);


  display.setTextSize(4);             // Draw 2X-scale text
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);

}

void loop() {
 testdrawstyles1();
 testdrawstyles2();
}


void testdrawstyles1(void) {
 display.clearDisplay();
 display.print(F("test1"));
 display.display();
 delay(500);
}

void testdrawstyles2(void) {
 display.clearDisplay();
 display.print(F("test2"));
 display.display();
 delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have to reset the cursor. I don't know if `clearDisplay` handles that for you.  Could you please try: `display.setCursor(0,0);` above each print statement. Perhaps, actually you print the text to "nirvana".

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Convert your comment to an answer please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As approved by the OP, the error was caused by not having reset the cursor to a visible position on the display. The text was written outside of the OLED.

It seems as the `clearDisplay()` method does not reset the cursor.

The solution is to change the following methods

```
void testdrawstyles1(void) 
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0,0); 
  display.print(F("test1"));
  display.display();
  delay(500);
}

void testdrawstyles2(void) 
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0,0); 
  display.print(F("test2"));
  display.display();
  delay(500);
}
```